# JavaScript: global array variable returned undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

JavaScript newbie here.  I've searched and searched for answers and can't seem to figure this out.  The arrays that I'm passing to a function aren't being passed as references properly.  I don't think this is an async issue like many posts allude to but I could be wrong.

I have global arrays that I'm passing to a function.  Inside the function, the arrays return their proper values, but when I try to access them outside of the function, they are undefined.

For context, I'm passing 3 arrays that hold the dry-bulb temperature, wet-bulb temperature, and hour that the measurements were taken for later calculations.  I've only included a few sample data points for brevity.  Sample code below:

```
function run(){
    var hour = [];
    var db = [];
    var wb = [];
    var cities = ["AB Edmonton","MI Detroit"];
    getData(hour, db, wb, cities); 
    //this shows undefined, although within getData it is accurate data
    alert(hour[1]);
}

function getData(hour, db, wb, cities){
    //i= drop-down selection index, set to zero for testing
    i=0;

    switch(cities[i]) {
        case "AB Edmonton":
            hour = [1,2,3];
            db = [15,18,21];
            wb = [10,13,20];
            break;
        //case "MI Detroit":....
    }

    //this shows accurate values in the alert window
    alert(cities[i] + " at hour:" + hour[i] + " the temp is:" + db[i]);

    return [hour, db, wb];
};
```

Comment: You can pass cities into your `getData` function or define it outside of the functions.  As it currently stands, cities is only defined within `run`, `getData` does not have access to it. Make sure to look into closures.

Comment: but they're not global arrays. You have specified them inside the run function so they only have that scope.

Comment: Why do you return them if you do not get the returned data?

Comment: So, I cannot tell you **why** this is happening, but it has to do with hour's scope. If you define the variable outside the function (without var; e.g. hour = 0), your code should not come back as undefined.

Comment: Put `getData();` into a variable. And I don't think you need to pass `hour, db, wb` to the function, you can only pass **cities**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run` assigns empty arrays to `hour`, `db` and `wb`. These are variables which are locally scoped to the `run` function.

It then calls `getData` and passes those arrays as arguments.

Inside `getData` new local variables (also named `hour`, `db` and `wb`) are declared and are assigned the three empty arrays that were passed when the function was called.

The function then ignores those values and *overwrites* them with **new arrays** (these ones have contents).

It then returns another new array which holds each of those arrays.

This brings us back to `run`. The return value of `getData` is ignored completely and the original arrays (which are still stored in the `hour`, `db` and `wb` variables that belong to `run`) are accessed (but they are still empty).

You can either:

- Manipulate the existing arrays inside `getData` instead of overwriting them. (e.g. `hour = [1,2,3]` may become `hour.push(1); hour.push(2); hour.push(3)`).
- Use the return value of `getData` (in which case you don't need to bother assigning values or passing the empty arrays in the first place). You could use an object instead of an array so you can have useful names instead of an order here too.

Such:

```
function run(){
    var cities = ["AB Edmonton","MI Detroit"];
    var data = getData(cities); 
    alert(data.hour[1]);
}

function getData(cities){
    //i= drop-down selection index, set to zero for testing
    var i=0; // Use locally scoped variables where possible
    var hour, db, wb;

    switch(cities[i]) {
        case "AB Edmonton":
            hour = [1,2,3];
            db = [15,18,21];
            wb = [10,13,20];
            break;
        //case "MI Detroit":....

    //this shows accurate values in the alert window
    alert(cities[i] + " at hour:" + hour[i] + " the temp is:" + db[i]);

    return { hour: hour, db: db, wb: wb];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, those aren't global variables. The one `hour` variable is local to `run()` in which it is declared with `var`, the other is local to `getData` in which it is declared as a parameter.

In your `getData` function you are overwriting the local variable (which initially has the value that was passed in by `run()`) in the line

```
 hour = [1,2,3];
```

and from thereon the two variables refer to different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getData(hour, db, wb, cities){ }
```

`hour`, `db`, etc are references to the initial Arrays.

When you write `hour = [1,2,3];`, the `hour` local references does not longer point to your desired Array, but to a new Array which you have just constructed: `[1,2,3]`. To fix this issue simply push values to the parameters
`hours.push(1,2,3);` so you won't overwrite your references.

This is the same problem that occurs when you do:

```
a = {x : 1};
function setX(obj) {
  obj = {x: 2};
}
function correctSetX(obj) {
  obj.x = 2;
}
```

The `setX` function will do nothing, while the `correctSetX` will correclty a to `{x : 2}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help!  I've posted how I edited my code to get it to work based on the comments.  A couple things:

-I've moved all variables to be local in the getData() function.  At least one of the comments gave the impression that it is better practice to keep variables local (forgive me, I am not a CSE guy by training, but I appreciate the tips and patience on your behalf)

-I wasn't able to simply use the .push method because the amount of data caused an error.  (there are at least 8760 measurements per year) I can't remember the exact error but it was related to stack limits

-At the suggestion of Quentin, I instead created a dataSet object that had array properties.  This object is what is returned by the getData function.  Thank you again, this was a much better way to handle this

Sample below (with limited data):

```
function run(){

    //get data
    var dataSet = getData(); 
    //test the result on the 2 hour reading
    alert(dataSet.hour[1]); 
}

function getData(){
//i= drop-down selection index, set to zero for testing
var i=0;
var hour,db,wb;
var cities = ["AB Edmonton","MI Detroit"];
switch(cities[i]){

    case "AB Edmonton":
        hour = [1,2,3];
        db = [10,11,12];
        wb = [13,14,15];
        break;
    //case "MI Detroit":...
} //end of switch

return {hour: hour, db: db, wb: wb};
}; //end of getData
```